# Is there anyway to burn/get tokens back from a contract address?

Tags: contract-development, tokens

I have a case here. Created a contract and sent some tokens to it. As of now, the contract is of not usable. The contract had `destroy` function as below.

```
  function destroy() onlyOwner {
    // Transfer tokens back to owner
    uint256 balance = token.balanceOf(this);
    assert(balance > 0);
    token.transfer(owner, balance);
  }
```

But, when the token contract was created, the `transfer` function was coded as below.

```
/**
* Internal transfer, only can be called by this contract
*/
function _transfer(address _from, address _to, uint _value) internal {
    // Prevent transfer to 0x0 address. Use burn() instead
    require(_to != 0x0);
    // Check if the sender has enough
    require(balanceOf[_from] >= _value);
    // Check for overflows
    require(balanceOf[_to] + _value > balanceOf[_to]);
    // Save this for an assertion in the future
    uint previousBalances = balanceOf[_from] + balanceOf[_to];
    // Subtract from the sender
    balanceOf[_from] -= _value;
    // Add the same to the recipient
    balanceOf[_to] += _value;
    Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
    // Asserts are used to use static analysis to find bugs in your code. They should never fail
    assert(balanceOf[_from] + balanceOf[_to] == previousBalances);
}
```

The line `require(balanceOf[_to] + _value > balanceOf[_to]);` is not allowing to `destory` as the `require` always fails during send all the available tokens.

Had created another contract just test the drain function with a different name as below which worked properly. And the contract in consideration was not coded like this (that has the destroy function as above)

```
  /**
   * @notice Terminate contract and refund to owner
   */
  function withdraw() onlyOwner external {
    address myAddress = this;
    if(myAddress.balance > 0)
        owner.transfer(myAddress.balance);
    uint256 tokBalance = token.balanceOf(this);
    tokBalance = tokBalance - (1 wei);
    if(tokBalance > 0)
        token.transfer(owner, tokBalance);
  }
```

Is there a way to burn/get back tokens from that contract? Though we can freeze the account, that doesn't help as we want to burn the tokens.  Second contract (from where to withdraw or burn token) is [here](https://github.com/RetainlyInc/retn-pre-ico-contract/blob/master/retn-preico.sol) and 0x1798F533e0cE9501dac8a831A0b02A4f35304FFd is the address of it

Comment: Can you explain why that `require` is failing? Is the `_to` account's balance overflowing?

Comment: Is it not supposed to be `>=` in the condition? because of just `>` this condition never met. I mean it supposed to be `require(balanceOf[_to] + _value >= balanceOf[_to]);`

Comment: I do think `>=` is better, but only because ERC20 usually allows transfers of `0`. It shouldn't cause a non-zero transfer to fail.

Comment: But am not able to execute that function, getting that high gas warning, and even if I try, the transaction gets failed

Comment: So you don't actually know it's that `require` statement? In that case, can you share a link to a failed transaction? And share the full source code for the two contracts (if they're not already verified on Etherscan)?

Comment: The token contract is verified here https://etherscan.io/address/0x2add07c4d319a1211ed6362d8d0fbe5ef56b65f6#code. And same contract available in rinkeby in which the withdraw failed. Transaction is here https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x29803f81972a8612ee64d875024428a2ed2232de1f3827751a8c64d0af3d7131. Had also created another contract with similar function with a little change to keep 1 Wei in the contract worked. Updated that in the question.

Answer (score 1):

From your link the issue is that you override `_transfer` in RETNToken

```
function _transfer(address _from, address _to, uint _value) internal {
    require (_to != 0x0);                               // Prevent transfer to 0x0 address. Use burn() instead

--->require (balanceOf[_from] > _value);                // Check if the sender has enough

    require (balanceOf[_to] + _value > balanceOf[_to]); // Check for overflows
    require(!frozenAccount[_from]);                     // Check if sender is frozen
    require(!frozenAccount[_to]);                       // Check if recipient is frozen
    balanceOf[_from] -= _value;                         // Subtract from the sender
    balanceOf[_to] += _value;                           // Add the same to the recipient
    Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
}
```

The solution is to replace that line by the correct one

```
require (balanceOf[_from] >= _value);
```

Comment: So, how do I get the tokens back from that another contract?

Comment: The solution is to replace that line by the correct: `require (balanceOf[_from] >= _value);`. If the contracts are already deployed there's not much you can do about it, if it is programmed in the contract you can approve a third party to do the transfer.

Comment: The contracts are already deployed. Can you explain bit more about approve third party to do transfer in the contract?

Comment: ERC20 tokens support using `approve` for token owners allow another third party make `transferFrom` from the owner balance. If your contract was programmed to call `approve` you can use it,if that is not the case then your tokens are locked inside of it.

Comment: But the balance are not with the owner. The token contract has the `approve`, but the contract in discussion just has `destroy`. Does this mean, no way to withdraw it? https://github.com/RetainlyInc/retn-pre-ico-contract/blob/master/retn-preico.sol is the code to the contract and 0x1798F533e0cE9501dac8a831A0b02A4f35304FFd is the address of it

Comment: I'm afraid if that is your contract there's nothing you can do. The PreIco contract will try to transfer the total amount of tokens but the token contract won't allow it. You should always create unit test at least for public functions.

Comment: Yeah, the token contract was picked from the ethereum.org/token when it had that bug. It was fixed much later after this contract deployment. Thanks Ismael. Not sure but I still feel there should be some workaround for this kind of cases.